# Query with joins and null columns

Tags: sql

```
select distinct scene.title,staff.job_descr
from actor
inner join scene
on scene.id=actor.id_scene 
left join staff
on scene.id=staff.Ids
```

This piece of code returns me all the(movie) scenes with the staff that's working at them.Some of the scenes have no staff members working on them,how can I display only those scenes?

```
Tile            job_descr 
First murder    makeup artist 
First scene     NULL
Guest singer    NULL 
Haunt scene 5   janitor    
New year concert    management
```

For example,above is a part of the results I'm receiving,I want to display only the second and third rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add condition in where clause like below

```
SELECT DISTINCT scene.title, 
                staff.job_descr 
FROM   actor 
       INNER JOIN scene 
               ON scene.id = actor.id_scene 
       LEFT JOIN staff 
              ON scene.id = staff.ids 
WHERE  staff.job_descr IS NULL
```

Comment: That's it.I was using `=` in where instead of `is`